# VideoCapture frames images corrupted: shifting one of the channels on random frames

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, video-capture

The camera works correctly, when I use the software to verify the camera I see no corrupted frames so I assume that this is issues are coming from OpenCV.

I notice that random frames (one out of 10-20 frames) are corrupted and one of the channels is shifted. Example below.

[image]

I am running the camera code as a service that runs in the background so any other application can obtain the latest frame and make use of it without having to run the read frame loop and work with asynchronous code.

```
import threading
import time
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

class CameraCU81():
    def __init__(self, W=1920, H=1080, hz=30):
        self.cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
        self.last_frame = None
        # if recording mjgp the frames hangs...
        #self.cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
        print(str(cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')))
        self.cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, W)
        self.cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, H)
        self.cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, hz)
        print('Starting camera 81 fps at: ' +  str(self.cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)))
        w = str(self.cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        h = str(self.cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        print('Starting camera 81 resolution at: ' + w + ' x ' + h)
        format = str(self.cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
        print('Starting camera 81 format: ' + format)

def __capture_frames(self):
    error_f = False
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if not ret:
            timeout_time = (time.time() - start_time)
            print('Frame could not be read ... is camera connected?')
            print(timeout_time)
            error_f = True
        else:
            self.last_frame = frame
            if error_f:
                timeout_time = (time.time() - start_time)
                print(timeout_time)

def get_data(self):
    return self.last_frame

def destroy(self):
    self.cap.release()

def run(self):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.__capture_frames)
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
```

Comment: It seems like a multi-threading issue. Like race condition. How can you make sure that while the data is being written, halfway through the other thread don't try to read the image?
I am not much familari with how numpy objects are being saved it seems to me that when you write `self.last_frame = frame` it is only a pointer assignement. but I am not sure.

Comment: this seems like the device is broken or ***network streaming*** has data loss. not an opencv issue. -- what happened to the greenery in your picture? looks smeared. who did that? -- code indentation is broken. in python, that is syntax, not cosmetic. [mre] required.

Comment: those artefacts come from JPEG decoding having to deal with data corruption. this happens somewhere between the camera compressing the frames, the path from there through wire and drivers, or opencv's video backend which decodes the JPEG frames. anything returned from cap.read() is already decoded. the corruption cannot have happened after that. "race conditions" cannot explain this. if you want to make sure, present a proper [mre] that DOES NOT use threading. since nobody but you can reproduce this anyway, we'll have to take your word for it. your success depends on your will to cooperate.

Comment: the "blurry" parts of the picture are very likely also from JPEG decode dealing with corruption, but there it's got more data to work with and is trying its best. you probably dismissed those areas and thought you'd have a little bit of defect in the top half... no, the whole picture is garbled. you should be suspicious of the pattern: *only* every other row of JPEG blocks is affected.

Comment: (unrelated to question) I never saw before when we need to set CAP_PROP_FOURCC? Why someone would do that? @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: Where is cv.imhow() and waitKey()?

Comment: It worked. I don't get image corrupted.

Comment: See my image https://imgur.com/a/MzROHpl

Comment: @Patrick Vibild. Please fix the indentation __capture_frames, get_data , destroy and run should be inside class , but not outside. It worked for me. I can see in debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some weeks I found out that I was hitting the USB throughput of my raspberry Pi 4. Connecting 2 cameras to USB3.0 was an issue.

Dropped resolution of one of my cameras and then connected one camera to the USB2.0 bus and the other one to USB3.0 bus.

Comment: curious! data rate limits are not _supposed_ to cause such issues because USB allocates data rate to devices. it should have noticed that it can't satisfy the allocation. this might be a driver bug you ran into, i.e. drivers in the linux kernel. maybe the rpi-specific code isn't as robust as the code for regular x86-64 systems.